# Uninstalled Game Optimizing Service on Samsung Galaxy A50 (Android 9) will be re-installed immediately

Tags: adb, samsung, bloatware

I am trying to uninstall Game Optimizing Service bloatware on Samsung Galaxy A50 (Android 9):

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.game.gos
```

As soon as i post this command, I see that GOS briefly disappears from the applications list, but then after a fraction of a second it re-appears again. Something is watching its state and re-enables it.

How to get rid of GOS bloatware?

Here is an excerpt from logcat:

```
2023-07-01 12:37:37.047 5088-5088/? I/VVM.VvmPkgInstalledRcvr: onReceive() : action android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED packageName :com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.048 4581-4581/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Remove alarm for next reason : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED : package: com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg - uid - 1000, key - PackageNameExternalStorageWhiteList, packageName- com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg : Not match found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : Match not found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg - uid - 1000, key - PackageNameExternalStorageBlackList, packageName- com.samsung.android.game.gos

2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage com.samsung.android.game.gosuserId - 0
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage userId - 0
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4602/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.samsung.android.game.gos flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.sec.imsservice/com.sec.internal.ims.imsservice.ImsIntentReceiver
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : adminUid - 1000
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg - uid - 1000, key - PackageNameExternalStorageWhiteList, packageName- com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg : Not match found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.055 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : Match not found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg - uid - 1000, key - PackageNameExternalStorageBlackList, packageName- com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg : Not match found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : Match not found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : adminUid - 10051
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg - uid - 10051, key - PackageNameExternalStorageWhiteList, packageName- com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg : Not match found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : Match not found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg - uid - 10051, key - PackageNameExternalStorageBlackList, packageName- com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: checkExternalStoragePkg : Not match found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? D/ApplicationPolicy: packageRemovedForExternalStorage : Match not found
2023-07-01 12:37:37.056 4581-4581/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.samsung.android.game.gos'!

2023-07-01 12:37:37.060 4581-4581/? I/ConditionProviders: Disallowing condition provider com.samsung.android.game.gos

2023-07-01 12:37:37.061 4581-4581/? D/AudioService: com.samsung.android.game.gos(10134) is removed

2023-07-01 12:37:37.069 4581-4581/? D/SdpManagerService.receiver: On android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED : DATA = package:com.samsung.android.game.gos, UID = 10134, UserId = 0, Is replacing? false

2023-07-01 12:37:37.075 4581-4813/? D/SdpManagerService: handlePackageRemoved - PackageName : com.samsung.android.game.gos, UserId : 0

2023-07-01 12:37:37.131 4581-4681/? D/[a11y]: getUserAccounts0
2023-07-01 12:37:37.133 4581-4681/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) AccountManagerS identical 3 lines
2023-07-01 12:37:37.133 4581-4681/? D/[a11y]: getUserAccounts0
2023-07-01 12:37:37.135 4972-5014/? D/EventHandler_FLP: PACKAGE_ADDED
2023-07-01 12:37:37.135 4972-5014/? D/PackageInfoManager_FLP: action : ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, packageName = com.samsung.android.game.gos
2023-07-01 12:37:37.136 4847-4847/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
2023-07-01 12:37:37.137 4847-4847/? D/MetaDataParser: updatePackage() com.samsung.android.game.gos true
2023-07-01 12:37:37.138 5049-5049/? D/RoutingNotificationHelper: set : ((5049) true , false)
2023-07-01 12:37:37.138 5049-5049/? D/RegisteredServicesCache: invalidateCache
2023-07-01 12:37:37.138 4847-4847/? D/MetaDataParser: removePackage() key = com.samsung.android.game.gos
```

Comment: Considering all your questions today you should really think about installing a custom ROM like LineageOS. That would get you more control and you could start free of Samsung and Google background services.